# Dlang how to make dub find external library

Tags: d

I'm trying to compile a **D** program with **dub**, using DSFML library.
I'm following a [sort of tutorial](https://github.com/Jebbs/DSFML/wiki/Building-Your-First-DSFML-Program%28DUB%29) which explains how to compile with dub a project with any "external" libray.
After creating a project, I try to compile with `dub build` and it says `dsfml-graphics.lib Warning 2: File Not Found dsfml-graphics.lib`, one warning for each .lib file.
Now, it my source doesn't contain any SFML object/class/related instruction, it obviously compile and generate a warning. If I use some SFML classes obviously no.
I suppose I made something wrong inside dub.json file, maybe in the `-lflag` tag, but I'm not sure. Any idea on **how to make dub find my DSFML .lib files?**

This is my directory tree:

```
>documents
>> DSFML
>>> bin (inside, .dll files)
>>> lib
>>>> dmd (inside, .lib files)
>>>> gcd (inside, .lib files)
>> d-test-dsfml (my dub's project)
```

And here my dub.json file:

```
{
    "name": "d-test-sfml",
    "description": "A minimal D application.",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2014, John",
    "authors": ["John"],
    "lflags" : ["+C:\\Users\\John\\documents\\DSFML"],
    "dependencies": {
        "dsfml:graphics": "~master",
    }
}
```

In -lflag, I also tried using [John user]\documents\DSFML\bin, lib, and lib\dmd.

**EDIT:** resolved, I just need to write `lib\\dmd\\` (ending with two `\\`). In 6 hours I'll mask it as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Write `"lflags" : ["+C:\\Users\\John\\documents\\DSFML\\lib\\dmd\\"]` with the two `\\` at the end. Now dub will find the .lib.
Like any other program, fter compiling put the .dll in `\\bin` files in the same directory of the .exe